# Web-Scrapping using python copy selector: I am not able to print the scrapped data of this website to my console. output is returning 0

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, css-selectors

```
import requests
import bs4
news=requests.get("https://www.darshan.ac.in/")
soap=bs4.BeautifulSoup(news.text,'lxml')
allnews=soap.select("body > main > div > div.js-ajaxContentLoad > div > div > div.masonry- 
grid.row>div:nth-child(n+2)") 
print(allnews)
```

The output is returning null.I am not able to print the scrapped data of this website to my console.I want to print the html of this selected div
but it is returning empty.

Comment: Please check your example code twice, `soap1` is nowhere defined - Would also be great, if you take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You access 2 URLs... why? What is your end goal?